# Is automatic nvidia driver installation with secure boot broken in ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, secure-boot

Has the automated installation of nvidia drivers broken with the latest ubuntu 20.04/xubuntu 20.04 installs in the case of a secure boot computer?

Background:
I have used ubuntu and xubuntu for at least 10 years on various desktops, servers and laptops. I have a laptop which is required to be in secure boot mode because of secure/encrypted windows. This laptop (Aero15x 2017, GTX 1070) with a discrete nvidia GPU which has run beautifully for years on 18.04 and 20.04 with periodic updates of the nvidia drivers automatically and without problem.

However in January, I assume after an update of al the packages (I believe including nvidia-driver-510.) It stopped booting. Grub comes up as usually, but when I selected the usual latest kernel the first two lines of the boot come up including loading the initramfs then locking up before the "Secure Boot" message.
I tried various repairs using a live usb of ubuntu 20.04 and xbuntu 20.04, both of which boot without difficulty using the nouveau driver.

I ultimately reinstalled first the latext ubuntu 20.04 then the latest xubuntu 20.04 and both install without difficulty. but when I use the "install additional drivers option" in the graphical software management panel, the lockup returns. I tried this with several versions of the driver (510, 470) and with several kernels that could be installed.

Ultimately it looks like the usual automatic signing/enrollment process is not happening.
I came up with a work around by download the runfile version of the nvidia driver (510) from the nvidia website and did a command line install and selected the "sign driver" option then used "MOK" to add the signature to my secureboot nvram after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

My steps to make it work with secure boot were as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I pressed then a menu labeled as "Perform MOK Management" appeared, there were the following four options:

1 . Continue boot 2 . Enroll Key 3 . Enroll Key from Disk 4 . EnrollKey from Hash

I chose option number 2, then I continued to boot, it finally worked, I went to Ubuntu settings->Details and my Graphic Card name was shown correctly.